# Advice / pointers / research on UX design for single pushwheel button

Tags: usability, navigation, input

I'm in the unfortunate position of having to design an UX for a mineral analysis machine where the input/output hardware is limited to an 8" LCD (non-touch) and a single "pushwheel" button (a wheel that can be turned in discrete steps and pushed).

I'm looking for good advice on how to design an UX for a system where the input is severely limited like this.

The UX must support, among other things:

- Navigating between a set of modes (main menu, start scan, show status et.c.)
- In some cases, entering numbers (drilled depth) and even alphabetic characters (drill hole IDs)
- Showing status and navigating a list of recent warnings/errors.
- Cancelling a scan.

But mostly I'm just looking for general advise that deals with the problems with such limited input abilities.

Thanks in advance for any pointers/reading suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problem. You have a wheel that can be turn front/back. And push button.

You can easily prototype such interface by simulating scrolling by **tab/shift+tab** and push like enter button.

The main thing is to put all elements in proper order (like **tab index**) and clearly highlight which button is selected currently.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a specific problem per se. I was mostly looking for general advise in case someone had been in the same situation. There's obviously no problem in building the navigational elements (menus), as it's quite natural to navigate those with a pushwheel. The harder parts are entering numbers/letters and other more complex operations. I'm also interested in what orientation for the menus is most natural when using a wheel (left <-> right, up <-> down, or even a circular menu?).

Comment: And regarding prototyping, yes that's what I do currently. The pushwheel even acts as a keyboard (through an Arduino we've programmed), giving Up/Down keypresses for left/right turns and Enter on push, so it's very easy to prototype. We're using Qt QML for the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other concerns, but the first one that comes to my mind is that the app should be designed to minimize the input of number and letters, as it is usually very cumbersome on this type of device...

When it is absolutely necessary to let users input letters/numbers, I would use smart defaults (popular choices for instance), autocompletion or something that reduces the number of letters available on the keyboard based on the remaining list of possibilities -> French railway does that when users have to input train station names - for instance when you've typed PAR, the only two letters you can select on the keyboard are I and E as there are only two stations left that match "PAR" -> "parIs" and "parEmpuyre") -> when there is only one choice left, it auto-selects it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Entering numbers/letters will be a rare operation, but unfortunately there's no way to cut it out completely. Most of the time, the machine will be pre-programmed with a list of hole IDs from a PC beforehand, but there will be situations where the operator must be able to add a new hole out in the field. There's no way in that situation for the program to know beforehand what is an allowed hole ID. In some cases, we may want to locally customize the machine by only allowing certain patterns (e.g "ABC-123", or "1234").

Comment: But even so, there must always be the possibility to enter a free-form hole ID.

Comment: I guess one thing we could possibly exploit is that many times, when adding a new hole ID, it will likely be similar to previously entered holes. E.g. say the machine currently has "ABC-001", "ABC-012" and "ABC-123", then it's likely that the new hole will have the format "ABC-NNN"..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one (slightly left-field) way to look at this would be to investigate accessibility research for people with [motor impairments](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/motor-impairment/) - people who find it difficult/impossible to use mouse/keyboard/touch inputs.

Some useful resources:
[How people with disabilities use the web](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/people-use-web/)

> To use the Web, people with physical disabilities often use specialized hardware and software such as:
>
> - Ergonomic or specially designed keyboard or mouse
> - Head pointer, mouth stick, and other aids to help typing
> - On-screen keyboard with trackball, joystick, and switches to operate it
> - Voice recognition, eye tracking, and other approaches for hands-free interaction

[Text input for motor-impaired people](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwito4adw8XMAhWCJhoKHWSmBCU4ChAWCEwwBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%252Fs10209-015-0433-0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHfsPq8RfEx_1yvb5LtblTk1GBfaA&sig2=R9voQCVzokRvRH9SyazQ1Q&bvm=bv.121421273,d.d2s)

[Assistive Technologies and Computer Access for Motor Impaired people [book]](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m96WBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&dq=Assistive%20Technologies%20and%20Computer%20Access%20for%20Motor%20Disabilities&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidl8Ldw8XMAhXCOBQKHe91BH8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Assistive%20Technologies%20and%20Computer%20Access%20for%20Motor%20Disabilities&f=false)

This maybe isn't an exact answer to your question, but hopefully provides a spark to investigate some other resources that may help!

Comment: That's a really interesting suggestion, and I'll look around a bit. Thanks for the pointers!